# Не корректно работает .toggleClass() jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Здравствуйте, есть сайт, фильтр которой открывается и закрывается с помощью функции .toggleClass(), сам код выглядит следующим образом:

```
$(".filter_section-toggler").on('click', function(){
  $(this).toggleClass( 'filter_section-value--current' );
  $(this).parent().parent().children('ul').slideToggle();
 })
$('.filter_section-value--current').parent('ul').css('display', 'block');
```

Но к сожалению, после установки "jquery mmenu", функция стала не корректно работать, пример можно посмотреть тут: http://www.postel-house.ru/?theme_preview=734554 , перейдя на пункт меню тут http://prnt.sc/ds56ck и нажав  http://prnt.sc/ds54m7 . Такое ощущение что функция два раза срабатывает, может быть я не прав, помогите пожалуйста

Comment: Где html, где css? "Посмотрите тут, посмотрите там" - добавьте код!

Comment: в дебаггере пройдитесь да и узнаете сколько раз срабатывает функция, и работает ли `.toggleClass()` в чем проблема то?